# How can I segment these Lemons seperately?

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, opencv

I have the following image and have to segment each lemon separately.

[image]

I have tried a few things and the best I could get is this.

[image]

The code I used:

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('lemons1.jpeg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower=(10,150,0)
upper=(100, 255, 80)
mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask1, None, iterations=5)

cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
blobs = 0
#Drawing contours and counting the lemons
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 4)
```

Comment: Hm... I was facing a similar problem but with leaves... I was having a hard time differentiating leaves it they overlapped in the image... I still haven't found the solution though :(

Comment: do you anything in advance, like the number of lemons in the image or their size(s) or an roi?

Comment: @Micka nothing is provided in advance. The actual problem is to find the number of lemons in the image and segment them. I found a way around the number of lemons part but have no solution to the segmentation part.

Comment: @Tanmay can you explain what ```cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
``` is doing?

Comment: Please consult the duplicate I've linked.  It is a way of segmenting out individual objects that all share the same shape and colour distribution in an image.  This will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: @rayryeng the link is really great and segmented the lemons collectively more accurately and smoothly, but it still is not segmenting them each individually.

Comment: Not true. You can use each of the markers derived from the marker image to help isolate out each lemon.